# How to get li tags attrbute data present under one particular section

Tags: jquery

I have got this  HTML

```
<ul>
   <section id="Home" class="ulseWrap lielement">
      <div class="intit someclassss">Home<span id="deleteHome" class="inDelete"></span></div>
   </section>
   <section id="Office" class="ulseWrap lielement">
      <div class="intit someclassss">Office<span id="deleteOffice" class="inDelete"></span></div>
      <ul class="restListings">
         <div class="inner-intit">
            <sub class="sub">Yours Favorite Restaurant</sub>
            <li class="innerChild" vendor_id="2">
            </li>
            <li class="innerChild" vendor_id="1">
            </li>
         </div>
      </ul>
   </section>
</ul>
```

When clicked on the class **inDelete** , i need to get all the **li** tags `vendor_id's` present under that particular section .

I tried this way , but i was getting error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string**  under browser console

```
$(document).on('click', '.inDelete', function(event ) {
var existingvendorids = [];
$(this).closest( "section li" ).each(function() {
 var vendor_id = $(this).attr("vendor_id");
 existingvendorids.push(vendor_id);
 });
});
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1ty1v8u1/9/

Please refer to the function  with the comment // This is called when clicked on GE KONE (DELETE ) in the jsfiddle which is doing this work .

I need all the vendor id's in the form of an array of all the li tags present in that particular section 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use, closest() to find the `section` and find() to get the `li` elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.inDelete', function (event) {
    var existingvendorids = $(this).closest("section").find('li').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("vendor_id");
    }).get();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much , but why is that i am getting the result when it is in expanded state only ?? (In jsfiddle Either expand Office Or HOME ) can't i get it in unexpanded state also .

Answer (score 1):

Try this : get parent `section` using `closest()` and then use `find()` to get all `li` under section

```
$(document).on('click', '.inDelete', function(event ) {
var existingvendorids = [];
$(this).closest("section").find("li").each(function() {
   var vendor_id = $(this).attr("vendor_id");
    existingvendorids.push(vendor_id);
 });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/1ty1v8u1/10/)**